# Swaggen external references fails with unresolved Reference

Tags: json, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to use SwagGen to generate client code from an OpenAPI 3.0 spec. The sample spec is https://github.com/yonaskolb/SwagGen/blob/master/Specs/Petstore/spec.yml (translated to json) and works fine when invoked with:

`swaggen generate spec.json`

I want to replace the components/schemas section with an external schema representing Pet:

```
      "schemas": {
         "Pet": {
            "required": [
               "id",
               "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int64"
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "tag": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },
```

with

```
      "schemas": {
         "Pet": {
            "$ref": "pet.json"
         },
```

where pet.json is in the same directory and looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-05/schema#",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schema/pet.json",
  "title": "Pet",
  "description": "Pet",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "id",
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "name": {
      "description": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tag": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

This gives me an error `Fatal error: Reference ./pet.json is unresolved: file /private/tmp/swaggen-20190424-43085-jvmk5p/SwagGen-4.1.0/Sources/Swagger/Component/Reference.swift, line 10
Illegal instruction: 4`

For some reason, when I use a #ref instead:

```
      "schemas": {
         "Pet": {
            "#ref": "./pet.json"
         },
```

generation succeeds. But, the generated Pet model is empty:

```
// Generated by SwagGen
// https://github.com/yonaskolb/SwagGen
//

import Foundation

public class Pet: APIModel {

    public init() {
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    }

    public func isEqual(to object: Any?) -> Bool {
      guard object is Pet else { return false }
      return true
    }

    public static func == (lhs: Pet, rhs: Pet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isEqual(to: rhs)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand why $ref results in an unresolved issue, why #ref kind of works, but results in an incorrect Pet model.

Comment: `$ref` is the correct keyword, `#ref` is not. Does `"$ref": "./pet.json"` work? Does it work if you remove `$schema` and `$id` from `pet.json`? (These JSON Schema keywords are [not supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) in OpenAPI.)

Comment: i'm thinking that `#ref` worked because of a bug in the generation code. I created an issue and it turns out `$ref` isn't currently supported in swaggen. Unclear whether that means any reference, since a local reference within a file seemed to work. Not planning on pursuing this further for now; see https://github.com/yonaskolb/SwagGen/issues/168. I'm going to start trying swagger-codegen for swift client generation since we could get server code generation working.